# Is there an English proverb similar to the Hindi "Elephant goes to the bazar; Thousands of dogs bark"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, proverb-requests

There is a proverb in Hindi language

> हाथी चले बाज़ार कुत्ते भौंकें हज़ार

Literal English translation:

> Elephant goes to the bazar; Thousands of dogs bark

It figuratively means when a person progresses with something or succeeds, the people often vilify him and protest. (So let them do what they do. A high-level person doesn't need anything to stop progressing or succeeding)

[image: image of dogs barking at elephant]

Comment: What is it you want the proverb to express? You have mentioned two *different* things in your question: (1) people protest success and (2) keep on doing your thing despite objections. There are now two answers, each addressing only one of these.

Comment: @JasonBassford, in its "extended" usage, the expression "sour grapes" embodies both.  It's a straightforward observation that success is being derided -- and, by imputing mere envy to the derisive people, it implicitly tells the successful person, "Ignore them, their opinions count for nothing."

Answer (score 3):

"Haters goin' to hate" fits pretty well.  Includes the existence of critics, and the inevitability of critics (for success or otherwise) and that life must go on.

Comment: I’ve never seen “haters goin’ to hate”. The more common variant is “haters gonna hate” or “haters gon’ hate”.

Answer (score 2):

The proverb:

***the dogs bark, but the caravan goes on***

although of foreign ([probably Turkish](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/the_dogs_bark,_but_the_caravan_goes_on)) origin, is listed in [Farlex Dictionary of Idioms](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/the+dogs+bark+but+the+caravan+goes+on).

---

Consider also:

> ***[sticks and stones may break my bones, but words will never hurt me](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/sticks+and+stones+may+break+my+bones%2C+but+words+will+never+hurt+me)***
>   A common childhood chant meaning hurtful words cannot cause any
>   physical pain and thus will be ignored or disregarded. *I've never been
>   affected by people's criticism—sticks and stones may break my bones,
>   but words will never hurt me.*

For origin, see: [Sticks and Stones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticks_and_Stones)

Comment: And both of these can be applied to the anonymous downvoters...

Comment: michael.hor257k, I agree with you though someone has downvoted your answer

Comment: michael.hor257k, hahaha you are right

Comment: I wasn't the downvoter so this is just a guess, but I see two problems:  (a) it's not really a commonly used proverb among native English speakers, and (b) it misses the sense given by the OP:  "It figuratively means when a person progresses with something or succeeds, the people often vilify him and protest."

Comment: Don't Australians have the "tall poppy syndrome"?

Comment: This is also a very common saying in Russian: "Собака лает, караван идет."  Its meaning is _nearly_ the same as the OP's, but subtly different: though dogs (bystanders or the rest of the world) may bark and criticize, the caravan just keeps going.  Both sayings boil down to "never mind what other people say; continue doing what you think is right" -  but they get there by different routes.

Comment: MT_Head, you are right

Answer (score 2):

There's a common English expression, **sour grapes,** which is fairly close to the meaning you describe.

Strictly speaking, it refers someone who is bitter over something he cannot have:

> **What's the meaning of the phrase 'Sour grapes'?**
>
> Acting meanly after a disappointment.
>
> **What's the origin of the phrase 'Sour grapes'?**
>
> In the fable The Fox and the Grapes, which is attributed to the ancient
>   Greek writer Aesop, the fox isn't able to reach the grapes and declares them
>   to be sour:
>
> A famished Fox saw some clusters of ripe black grapes hanging from a
>   trellised vine. She resorted to all her tricks to get at them, but
>   wearied herself in vain, for she could not reach them. At last she
>   turned away, beguiling herself of her disappointment, and saying: "The
>   Grapes are sour, and not ripe as I thought."

https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/sour-grapes.html

However you will often hear this meaning extended to a person who is envious of someone else's success.  For example, this snippet appears in an online blog that is discussing the tremendous financial success of Apple:

> Apple is the second largest computer maker IN THE WORLD. This year or
>   next, analysts predict they will become the largest computer maker in
>   the world, bar none. So, is the negativity really caused by a "Bad
>   Apple" or is it just "sour grapes" from people who still think it is
>   1995?

Comment: DM-GBG, sour grapes is a cunning fox story which is very common in India

Answer (score 0):

Not very common, but applicable:

> It is in the character of very few men to honor without envy a friend who has prospered.
>
> -- [Aeschylus](http://www.wiseoldsayings.com/envy-quotes/)