# Does the barking of a dog diminish the value of a priest?

Tags: meaning, idiom-meaning, metaphors

> **Does  a  barking  of  a dog  diminish the   value  of  a  priest?**

*The  above  is  an  Idiom  from Indian languages.A  dog  stands metophorically  for  the inferior  people.The  priest  stands for  the  people  who  are intellectually  and  spiritually great.The  meaning of  the  idiom  is that  the  profane people  never  diminish the  greatness  and  holiness  of  great  people simply  by  mocking at them*

What  is  the  equal  idiom in  English  apart  from the  saying  of  the  Egyptians.

> **"A profane person might be tempted to  violate the  tomb"**

Edit  :    *My  question  is  not  a  duplicate  because the  idiom  is  different  from  other  idioms : it  is  the  tendency  of  a dog  to  bark  at  a thief  or  at  a priest . It  can not  distinguish  between  good  and  bad.Every  new  person  seems  to  be  a thief  to a dog.So  great  people  are  great  people  even if  the  inferior  people  do  not  recognise  them or  mock at them.The  distance between  the  great  and  the  profane  is  always too long*

Comment: The concept sounds “undemocratic” to a western mind.

Comment: @ user067531.In what  way  does  it   sound 
 undemocratic?

Comment: a rose by any other name would smell as sweet? The 'it's the same thing no matter what' implication.

Comment: Which saying in the Bible are you referring to?

Comment: I think  the  quotation  is  from the  holy  Bible.

Comment: 'Sticks and stones may break my bones, _but names will never hurt me_.' is ball-park.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an English proverb similar to the Hindi "Elephant goes to the bazar; Thousands of dogs bark"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/467133/is-there-an-english-proverb-similar-to-the-hindi-elephant-goes-to-the-bazar-th). According to @michael.hor257k: '**the dogs bark, but the caravan goes on**' ... although of foreign (probably Turkish) origin, is listed in Farlex Dictionary of Idioms.

Comment: There are many idioms that mean something like this, but they are not kept around very long, and are generated afresh very often. The current idiom is "fake news."  An older version is "pity the fool."

Comment: @Englishmonger - It appears to be a quote from [An Account of the Manners and Customs of the Modern Egyptians](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Sl8nDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA482&lpg=PA482&dq=lest+its+value+should+tempt+any+profane+person+to+violate+the+tomb&source=bl&ots=Q72K5h2rma&sig=ACfU3U3EHbqo5MU-YSIXEMHBavb6NT2GtQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiy1Ku-38blAhXNUhUIHbjjBHAQ6AEwAHoECAUQAQ#v=onepage&q=lest%20its%20value%20should%20tempt%20any%20profane%20person%20to%20violate%20the%20tomb&f=false) by Edwin William Lane, not from the bible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A contemporary idiom with a similar sense is **haters gonna hate**. (NB I originally thought it was **haters gotta hate**, and probably both have some currency).

> The phrase implies that criticism says more about the critic, or "hater," than the person being criticized, i.e., that they are making judgements out of jealousy or their own negativity.
>   ([Source: dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/e/slang/haters-gonna-hate/))